# How to return a key if the value equal to specific value using jq in json parsing

Tags: json, jq

I have json file like this

```
{
  "version": "4.6.0",
  "flags": {
    "T1": true,
    "T1c": false,
    "T2": false,
    "FLAIR": false
  },
  "shapes": [],
  "imagePath": "HC-002_LM-0000_aparc+aseg_1mm_bin.png",
  "imageData":xxxxxxxxx
}
```

and I need the output to be

```
T1
```

as the value is true, Please suggest correct use of jq here, thanks!

Comment: Do you know you're only looking for keys nested under `flags`, or can't that be assumed?

Comment: Yes, only keys under `flags` is needed

Answer (score 4):

Use `to_entries` to access field name and value of an object's items and `select` those you need:

```sh
jq --raw-output '.flags | to_entries[] | select(.value).key'
```

```
T1
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/wdfq4ZyO5X)

Comment: works perfectly, cool!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ruby:

```
ruby -r JSON -e 'd=JSON.parse($<.read)
puts "T1" if d["flags"]["T1"]
' file
T1
```